# React redirect seo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I'm defining some redirects for a new react website.

Currently I'm using the Redirect component from the react-router-dom package.

Is this a bad way to redirect for SEO?

This is what the official documentation says:

> Rendering a Redirect will navigate to a new location. The new
>   location will override the current location in the history stack, like
>   server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

If this is a good way, Is there a way to give a status code with the redirect? (like 301)

Thanks in advance.